# MineSweeper map creator with python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create some sort of minesweeper map creator but having a difficult time with it.
the script is supposed to get a number of columns and lines of the map and then takes the number of bombs and their positions.

in the created map bombs should be shown as `*` and other cells should include the number of bombs in their neighbor(diagonally included)

**(For example):**

```
* 1
1 1
```

or

```
* 3 3 * 
* 3 * * 
1 2 2 2
```

**My code:**

```
#takes the number of colmuns and lines from user
xy=input()
xy=xy.split(" ")
m=int(xy[0])
n=int(xy[1])
#takes the number of the bombs
number=int(input())
bomb=[""]*number
matrix = [[0 for x in range(m)] for y in range(n)] 
#take position of the bombs
for i in range(number):
    bomb[i]=input()
    
for i in range(number):
    
    o=bomb[i].split(" ")
    x=int(o[0])-1
    y=int(o[1])-1
    #puts * in matrix as bombs
    matrix[y][x]="*"
    #checks the neighbor cells of the bomb
    for j in range(-1,2):
        for k in range(-1,2):
            
            #shouldnt check the bombs cell
            if j!=0 or k!=0:
                #ignores some type and index errors
                try:
                    matrix[y+j][x+k]+=1
                except:
                    pass
                    
                        
                        
#turn the matrix to desired format
for i in range(m):
    string=""
    for j in range(n):
        string+=str(matrix[j][i])+" "
    print(string)
```

with input like this:

```
2 2 #columns and lines
1   #number of bombs
1 1 #postion of bombs all in separate lines
```

it should return:

```
* 1
1 1
```

but it returns:

```
* 2
2 4
```

I cant figure out what's going wrong here

Comment: What does "tedad" store?

Comment: What is `tedad`?

Comment: Your attempt to use try/except for bounds checking doesn't do what you think it does. Are you aware of how Python handles negative indexes?

Comment: @Dock its the same as ```number``` forgot to change it

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica is not just for bounds it's also for type errors that happen. even with if statement the result doesn't change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like people pointed out in the comments, you don't handle negatives properly. An example:

```py
print(["hi", "hello"][-1])
```

outputs `hello`. This is because -1 would be the last element. And -2 would be the second to last, and so on, meaning it handles these perfectly fine without an error. This means you should check to see if the number is greater than -1, by doing

```py
if j!=0 or k!=0:
    #ignores numbers less than 0
    if y + j > -1 and x + k > -1:
        matrix[y+j][x+k]+=1
```